# Is there a more elegant way to handle HttpRequest body content in Dart?

Tags: dart

With the release of the new dart:io libraries, in order to read the data from an [HttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpRequest.html) we now need to:

> Listen to the body to handle data and notified of it's completion.

In order to accomplish this, I've been using something similar to the following to get all of the data from the request (taken from the dart:io tests):

```dart
List<int> body = new List<int>();
request.listen(body.addAll, onDone: () {
  var str = new String.fromCharCodes(body);
  // Now do something with the string of data
});
```

Is there some way of using [transform](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpRequest.html#transform) and/or [StringDecoders](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/StringDecoder.html) to already provide a constructed result. The only way I can think of, I would still need to create a StringBuffer and use writeAll to ensure all data is passed in the event it doesn't all arrive at once, and still call the onDone before using the string in the buffer.

So I guess ultimately the question is: is there some way I can use a HttpRequest (or in all actuality any Stream) without needing to buffer/build the results and can just pass a callback or handler which receives the entire contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I think you should be able to use StringDecoder, toList() and join() to get the whole body:

```dart
request.transform(new StringDecoder()).toList().then((data) {
  var body = data.join('');
  print(body);
}
```

Comment: So ultimately the answer is no at the moment there's not a way of doing it without a builder of some type. I agree per your other comment. There should be an easier way. I'll make a bug request.